# Apply style for a random collection of items

Tags: javascript

Bellow  i generate a random number of span and after that i want to apply random color and random distance for each element. The span's are generated but i cant apply the rest of my code, how to solve this?

```js
const elem = document.querySelectorAll('.elem')
 
    setInterval(() => {
        //generate a  random nr of elements
        const e = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
        var myHTML = '';
        var wrapper = document.querySelector(".container");
    
        for (let index = 0; index < e; index++) {
            myHTML += "<span class='elem'>" + index + "</span>"
        }
        wrapper.innerHTML = myHTML
        //apply random colors  and random distance
        const colors = ['blue', 'red', 'gray', 'yellow', 'black'];
        const randomColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
        for (let i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
            const a = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 600);
            const b = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 1600);
            elem[i].style.top = a + 'px';
            elem[i].style.left = b + 'px';
            elem[i].style.backgroundColor = randomColor;
        }
    }, 1000);
```

```css
.elem {
    background-color: gray;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    transition: 0.6s  ease-in;
    color: transparent;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">

    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to select the elements before the `setInterval` function, so `elem` always remains empty. To fix this, you need to put `const elem = document.querySelectorAll('.elem');` into the `setInterval` function.

**I also have a few other recommendations:**

- Use `document.getElementsByClassName("");` instead of `document.querySelectorAll("");` when selecting elements based on their class, as it is faster.
- Assign the length of an array to a variable before looping to prevent the `length` property having to be constantly accessed, improving performance.

```js
setInterval(() => {
  //generate a  random nr of elements
  const e = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  var myHTML = '';
  var wrapper = document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0];

  for (let index = 0; index < e; index++) {
    myHTML += "<span class='elem'>" + index + "</span>";
  }
  wrapper.innerHTML = myHTML;
  //apply random colors  and random distance
  const colors = ['blue', 'red', 'gray', 'yellow', 'black'];
  const randomColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
  const elem = document.getElementsByClassName('elem');
  const length = elem.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    const a = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 600);
    const b = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 1600);
    elem[i].style.top = a + 'px';
    elem[i].style.left = b + 'px';
    elem[i].style.backgroundColor = randomColor;
  }
}, 1000);
```

```css
.elem {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.6s ease-in;
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

</div>
```